# Sum() when using Group by is totaling Incorrectly

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a MYSQL query that is not summing correctly and i don't see the error in my the query.

```
SELECT s.source, vanMoney.userid, vanMoney.Username, vanMoney.vandate, vanMoney.FirstBuy, vanMoney.LastBuy, vanMoney.SourceID, vanMoney.TodayDate,
Sum(inv_temp.cost* inv_temp.quantity) as TotalCost,
Sum(inv_temp.quantity) as TotalQTY
FROM source AS s 
Left JOIN inv_temp ON inv_temp.source_id = s.source_id 
Left JOIN vanMoney ON inv_temp.source_id = vanMoney.SourceID 
WHERE s.buyer_type_id = 6 and quantity>0 
group by vanMoney.vandate, vanMoney.userid
```

[image: Results for Query]
The column TotalCost and TotalQTY are summing for the entire Source not just for the source and vandate

i have edited to add the following information
[image: vanMoney table ex.]
[image]

```
 the output i should get is 
for userid 186 on 3/9/2018 is TotalCost=7 and TotalQTY=2
for userid 186 on 3/10/2018 is TotalCost=77 and TotalQTY=2
for userid 186 on 3/11/2018 is TotalCost=4 and TotalQTY=2
for userid 179 on 3/26/2018 is TotalCost=30 and TotalQTY=2
```

Comment: Your query is invalid.  What is the reason you think you even need to use `GROUP BY`?

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid. Will raise an error on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode), and return unpredictable data with older versions. The general GROUP BY rule says: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Comment: You example query is missing TotalCost  and TotalQTY ?

Comment: The vandate condition in the WHERE clause makes that LEFT JOIN to return INNER JOIN result. Move that condition to ON to get true LEFT JOIN result.

Comment: you have no aggregation- how are you getting totalcost and totalqty?

Comment: i have edited with correct code (that is not working)

Comment: Code doesn't even run.  Fix your `GROUP BY` first.  Then we talk about fixing your query.

Comment: @ScottmikeForgiven Could you show your expect result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in order for the query to not sum the entire row but just the rows corresponding to the date i did a where= statement

```
SELECT
vanMoney.userid,
vanMoney.Username,
vanMoney.vandate,
Max(vanMoney.FirstBuy) AS firstbuy,
Max(vanMoney.LastBuy) AS lastbuy,
vanMoney.SourceID,
inv_temp.date_created,
Sum(inv_temp.cost* inv_temp.quantity) AS TotalCost,
Sum(inv_temp.quantity) AS TotalQTY,
source.source
FROM
inv_temp
LEFT JOIN vanMoney ON inv_temp.purchased_by = vanMoney.userid
Left JOIN source ON inv_temp.source_id = source.source_id
where date_created=vandate
GROUP BY  
vanMoney.vandate,
      vanMoney.userid
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `GROUP BY` clause you need to declare all field without aggregation
Function.

Using `SUM` aggregation with `GROUP BY` by `source_id` on subquery, you might get `totle` by `source_id`,then `JOIN` them.

You can try this.

```
SELECT s.source, 
       vanmoney.userid, 
       vanmoney.username, 
       vanmoney.vandate, 
       vanmoney.firstbuy, 
       vanmoney.lastbuy, 
       vanmoney.sourceid, 
       vanmoney.todaydate, 
       inv_temp.TotalCost, 
       inv_temp.TotalQTY 
FROM   source AS s 
       LEFT JOIN 
       (
        SELECT source_id,
               Sum(cost * quantity) AS TotalCost,
               Sum(quantity) AS TotalQTY
        FROM inv_temp
        WHERE quantity > 0 
        GROUP BY source_id
       ) inv_temp
              ON inv_temp.source_id = s.source_id 
       LEFT JOIN vanmoney 
              ON inv_temp.source_id = vanmoney.sourceid 
WHERE  s.buyer_type_id = 6
```

**EDIT**

`inv_temp` expect result query might be like

```
SELECT source_id,
       date_created,
       Sum(cost * quantity) AS TotalCost,
       Sum(quantity) AS TotalQTY
FROM inv_temp
WHERE quantity > 0 
GROUP BY source_id,
         date_created
```

> https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9yVD8cdV9iGnUQGiJ9vmFk/0

From your edit answer I guess you want to use like this.

```
SELECT s.source, 
       vanmoney.userid, 
       vanmoney.username, 
       date_format(str_to_date(vanmoney.vandate, '%m/%d/%Y'),'%Y%m'), 
       vanmoney.firstbuy, 
       vanmoney.lastbuy, 
       vanmoney.sourceid, 
       vanmoney.todaydate, 
       Sum(inv_temp.cost * inv_temp.quantity) AS TotalCost, 
       Sum(inv_temp.quantity)                 AS TotalQTY 
FROM   source AS s 
       LEFT JOIN inv_temp 
              ON inv_temp.source_id = s.source_id 
       LEFT JOIN vanmoney 
              ON inv_temp.source_id = vanmoney.sourceid 
WHERE  s.buyer_type_id = 6 
       AND quantity > 0 
GROUP  BY  s.source, 
           vanmoney.userid, 
           vanmoney.username, 
           date_format(str_to_date(vanmoney.vandate, '%m/%d/%Y'),'%Y%m'), 
           vanmoney.firstbuy, 
           vanmoney.lastbuy, 
           vanmoney.sourceid, 
           vanmoney.todaydate
```

> https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9yVD8cdV9iGnUQGiJ9vmFk/2

Comment: same issue totaling entire column for that source_id not for just the total for that data and source_id

Comment: Could you provide some sample data from those table and your expect result?

Comment: What is your expected vandate `group by` your prediction look like?

Comment: yes the query works fine when stand alone but once it is joined with vanMoney table it still totals everything

Comment: @ScottmikeForgiven 
The problem is not the same time in `vandate` You can try my second query